# How can I limit a trigger to only one trade

Tags: trading, pine-script-v5

In pinescript. How to limit a trigger to only one trade/entry, and after an exit not generate another entry from the same trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using:

```
b = ta.barssince(id2)
tradesActively = ((strategy.closedtrades - strategy.closedtrades[b]) < 1)
```

Variable `id2` is the trade setup condition.